# First row in tableview doesn't disappear after complete or delete action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that is populated when a user adds a record. This data is stored in the real-time firebase. Swiping right allows the user to complete the task and moves the record from the repair child to the complete child. Swiping left allows the user to delete the row. In both cases the row is removed from the table. This works fine for every row except for the first. When the user performs either of these actions the real time database performs the functions correctly; however, the first row retains the data. What am I missing?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.doListTableView.delegate = self
    self.doListTableView.dataSource = self


    //implement Google ADMobs
            // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
            bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

            addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.load(GADRequest())
            bannerView.delegate = self

    //get reference to firebase database
    refRepairs = Database.database().reference().child("repairs").child(UserID!);

        //observing the data changes
        refRepairs!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.repairList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for repairs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let repairObject = repairs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let brand  = repairObject?["brand"]
                let id  = repairObject?["id"]
                let categories = repairObject?["categories"]
                let modelNumber = repairObject?["modelNumber"]

                //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                let repair = RepairModel(id: id as! String?, categories: categories as! String?, brand: brand as! String?, modelNumber: modelNumber as! String?)

                self.repairList.append(repair)


            }
            //reloading the tableview
            self.doListTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let complete = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: "Complete") { (action, view, completion) in


                let repairList = self.repairList[indexPath.row]

                if let selectedRepairItem = repairList.id {

                    Database.database().reference().child("completed").child(self.UserID!).child(selectedRepairItem).setValue(["id": repairList.id, "brand": repairList.brand, "categories": repairList.categories, "modelNumber": repairList.modelNumber])
                    Database.database().reference().child("repairs").child(self.UserID!).child(selectedRepairItem).removeValue()

                }

                self.doListTableView.reloadData()


        }
                //        complete.image = //... Add an image
                complete.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
                let action = UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [complete])
                action.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true //... Full swipe support
                return action
}

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let repairList = self.repairList[indexPath.row]
    if let selectedRepairItem = repairList.id {
        Database.database().reference().child("repairs").child(UserID!).child(selectedRepairItem).removeValue()
        self.doListTableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

I had this working great but I ran into an issue with signing out. I fixed the issue but now I have to figure this out. Not sure why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //print(repairList.count)
    return (repairList.count)
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RepairTableViewCell
    let repair: RepairModel

    repair = repairList[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelBrand.text = repair.brand
    cell.labelModelNumber.text = repair.modelNumber

    return(cell)
}
```

Here's my model:

```
class RepairModel {

    var id: String?
    var categories: String?
    var brand: String?
    var modelNumber: String?

    init(id: String?, categories: String?, brand: String?, modelNumber: String?){
        self.id = id
        self.categories = categories
        self.brand = brand
        self.modelNumber = modelNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the DataSource methods?

Comment: It looks like you are not removing the object from your repairlist array.

Comment: I updated the above code. I think the repairlist array is pulling the object from my firebase database. When i move it from the child "repair" to the child "complete" the table shouldn't have any value to show. Am I  wrong here?

Comment: @Dale I updated the code. Let me know if this is what you are looking for. I am still having this problem and I completely changed the way a user logs in. I know it doesn't have anything to do with it but I am at my wits ends. Please help!

Comment: @MitsMistri you're right! Thanks. Not sure why its different this time around. A closer look and some changes and your were right on the money! Thanks for the help!